# Convert require() without assignment to import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, commonjs

file1.js

```js
console.log("foo")
```

file2.js

```js
require("./file1")
```

```sh
➜ node file2.js
foo
```

How would I convert file2.js's `require` to `import` and keep the same logic (so no assignment)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like below, this will import file1 to file2

```
import './file1';
```

This is useful when you want to execute the file1 code but does not want to assign it to the variable.
ex:

- create a database connection if you don't need a connection object.
- TypeScript compiler generates JavaScript completely without a
  module definition.